# Which editions of Visual Studio 2010 have SharePoint 2010 project/item templates?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I would like to know which editions of Visual Studio 2010 have SharePoint 2010 project templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231592):

> To build SharePoint solutions, the development computer must have the
>   correct version of SharePoint server installed. Otherwise, building
>   SharePoint solutions is the same as building other types of projects
>   in Visual Studio. For more information, see How to: Build SharePoint
>   Solutions.

So I'd expect this to mean any version of Visual studio apart from Express can be used, but to get the templates you need to install the development support/tools when installing the Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm certain this question is a duplicate.

At any rate, the answer is "all except Express". See [Visual Studio 2010 Comparison](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison).